# jquery - zclip and ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zclip

I'm using a jquery plugin named [zclip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/), which copies a string to the clipbvoard using a swf file.

I got zclip to work with my website, but I need the string to come from another page using ajax

Here's zclip code:

```
jQuery('.copyme').zclip({
    path:swf_path,
    copy:"text to copy goes here"
});
```

The above works, however it doesn't work when I place it in an ajax call as shown below.

```
jQuery('.copyme').click(function () {       
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: testUrl,
        data: "test",
        success: function(data){ 
            jQuery('.copyme').zclip({
                    path:swf_path,
                    copy:data
            });
        }               
    });
});
```

I believe it doesn't work because zclip is triggered on a mousevent, and when you put it inside an ajax call, there's no event. The event happened way before. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the data before the actual click happens, such as on `document.ready`.

```
$(function() {
    $.post(testUrl, {
        data: 'test' // data posted must be key-value pairs, btw
    }, function(data) {
        $('.copyme').zclip({
            path: swf_path,
            copy: data
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TREmT/

Comment: It's not a good idea to fetch before the actual click event occurs. You might have null data if the user clicked before the AJAX success call. Just put thing in `$('.btnCopy').click(function () {`